# Populating DataGridView using DataGridView.DataSource property and BindingSource

Tags: c#, datagridview, anonymous, concrete

The following two code snippets  populate a BindingSource which is  later assigned to 
a DataGridView.DataSource.

When the concrete class  QuotesTool.LineItem is used (first snippet)  the grid DOES NOT display the appropriate data:

BindingSource lineList = new BindingSource();

```
        foreach (XElement y in _lines.Elements())
        {
            lineList.Add(new QuotesTool.LineItem(
                y.Element("Vendor").Value,
                y.Element("Model").Value,
                y.Element("Selling_Unit").Value,
                y.Element("Net_Price").Value,
                y.Element("Spec").Value
                       ));
        }
```

But, if an anonymous type is used the grid displays data OK:

```
        foreach (XElement y in _lines.Elements())
        {
            lineList.Add(
              new {
                vendor = y.Element("Vendor").Value,
                Model = y.Element("Model").Value,
                UOM = y.Element("Selling_Unit").Value,
                Price = y.Element("Net_Price").Value,
                Description = y.Element("Spec").Value
            });
        }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing `QuotesTool.LineItem`, but **by default** to be useful, each member:

- must be public
- must be a property (not a field)
- must not be marked `[Browsable(false)]`

The issue here is *usually* one of the first two. For example, none of these will work by default:

```
public string Vendor;

internal string Vendor {get;set;}

[Browsable(false)] public string Vendor {get;set;}
```

but this will:

```
public string Vendor {get;set;}
```

Note that it doesn't have to be an automatically implemented property, nor does it need to be writeable:

```
private readonly string vendor;
public string Vendor { get { return vendor; } }
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. Changing class fields to Properties did the trick!

Comment: @user575719 good; public fields are *universally* a bad idea, to be honest. If this answers your question, please consider clicking the green "tick" to next to the answer, to mark it complete.